# Kaltura's two different iOS SDK and its implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, kaltura

According to [Kaltura documentation](http://knowledge.kaltura.com/kaltura-player-sdk-ios):

There are two ways to install Kaltura SDK, one is `pod` and other is traditional way to drag and drop Kaltura SDK.

1) Traditional Way : https://github.com/kaltura/player-sdk-native-ios has KPViewController class, which is used to play video as per the documents. but not having `KalturaPlayer` class.

2) POD installation : **pod 'player-sdk-native-ios', '~> 1.1'**  they provided `KalturaPlayer` class which is not present in https://github.com/kaltura/player-sdk-native-ios

And `[[KPViewController alloc] initWithURL:iFrameURL];` gives the error KPViewController doesnt have initWithURL method.

3) according to demo app : https://github.com/kaltura/IOSReferenceApp
they have installed the sdk traditional way but yet they have `KalturaPlayer` class. And `drawPlayer` method from `MediaInfoViewController_iPhone.m` has implementation of playing video ,yet it is not playing video for me, so I'm directly calling a method `playButtonPressed` from same class, which calls method `playVideo` from `PlayerViewController_iPhone` class and it plays video but the methdod playVideo opens `MPMoviePlayerViewControllerwhich` is different from `KalturaPlayer`

So which SDK should I use and if use POD sdk then is it the right way to play the Video because it plays in MPMoviePlayerViewController rather than KPViewController ?

And one more, is there pod installation available for `KalturaClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally use **Pods** when available. They are the state-of-the-art in library management on iOS. You can find the COCOAPOD `KalturaPlayerSDK` on [cocoapods.org](https://cocoapods.org/?q=Kaltura).

**Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'SO-32391714' do
pod 'KALTURA'
end
```

*As mentioned by @SML, some classes may be poorly documented in the Pod. I have no better suggestion than to contact their [Tech Support](http://corp.kaltura.com/content/technical-support).*

Comment: @SwiftArchitecht thanks. i didnt know how to check pod on cocoapods.org.now i m using the latest SDK using POD. but some classes are new which they (Kaltura) havent mentioned how to use in their Documentation.